# @import url('my.site/my-style.css') not working

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I have this line at the bottom of my WordPress style.css file:

```
@import url("http://my.site/wp-content/themes/mytheme/my-styles.css");
```

If I enter `http://my.site/wp-content/themes/mytheme/my-styles.css` into a web browser the file resolves and can be downloaded.

However, none of the styles in `my-styles.css` are being read.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why are you using @import? WordPress has its own default function wp_enqueue_style for adding css files

Comment: That would be a separate SO question but by all means go ask it. Then ping me and I'll answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@import` rule has to come first in your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

You If you want to create a custom CSS put your customization on it and make a file named `my-styles.css` and upload it on your theme main style sheet directory. then this will work as override the main style.

or 
example of how you can create a child theme and import the main CSS